# google cloud data Prep - error when importing dataset from BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataprep

When I tring to import bigquery tables as dataset in my data Prep flow, I have the following error:

Could not create dataset: I/o error.

I tried to import many bigquery tables (which are from same BQ dataset) all of them  successfully imported except this which has many columns (more than 2700 columns!). 
Maybe that's because of the large number of columns but I can't see any such limitation in Docs!

when I selecet the table ----> I have this message "Preview not available" like this:
[image]

and after clicking "import":
[image]

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening or has any suggestion?

Comment: Some It seems to happen on big datasets on my side too (around 80k rows and 2000 columns). Tried advanced settings and removing type inference but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Dataprep documentation doesn't have maximum columns limitation, thus it's not probable that this is the problem.

On the other hand, I have seen generic messages like 'I/O error' or simply red icons when importing data, and they are related to the [data type conversion between Dataprep and BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/BigQuery-Data-Type-Conversions_102563896#accessread).

I think that finding the types in BQ that are not compatibles in Dataprep and converting to one compatible should solve your issue.